# How to include a .h file correctly in VC++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a very simple C++/CLI window form program which is 100% working alright.

Since I want to add call internet explorer when I click a button on my window form, I add "ONE LINE of code" for testing purpose.

I add **#include "Shellapi.h"** under **#pragma once**. After that, VS gives me 500 lines of an error message.

My question is that I am only adding a .h file into my program. Why there will cause any problem? Do I miss something?

===========The first few lines of the error message===============

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(56): error C2065: 'HDROP' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(56): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'UINT'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'STDAPICALLTYPE'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Shellapi.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: If you can include the first few lines of errors here, that would likely help you get a resolution.  Is this really C++/CLI?

Comment: @SteveTownsend You are right, I should put more information. I am doing C++/CLI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things:

1. You should `#include <windows.h>` in any windows program
2. You should include any system file - like shellapi.h - using brackets (`<>`) instead of quotes (`""`), e.g. `#include <shellapi.h>`
3. If you're compiling from the command line, it's a good idea to run "vcvars32.bat" (or equivalent) to set your command-line environment for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to `#include <windows.h>` ***before*** `#include <shellapi.h>`

Generally, (or atleast in my personal experiences), when you are bombarded with a wall of errors after including a header, your missing `<windows.h>` or some other header.